# Jest sometimes cannot find modules

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I got this problem:

Sometimes jest cannot find modules while running tests. it's totally random module each time, not the same one. First one or two test suits fails because of that, rest are passing. Sometimes everything is okay. I use babel.

jest config in package.json

```
"jest": {
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.jsx"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  },
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "babel-jest",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$": "<rootDir>/fileMock.js"
  },
  "setupFiles": [
    "./testsSetup.js"
  ],
  "testURL": "http://localhost"
},
```

testSetup.js

```
const { configure } = require('enzyme')
const Adapter = require('enzyme-adapter-react-16')

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

i run tests with `npm test` set to `jest --color --coverage --notify`

is there something i lack in my config or something wrong here? couldn't find an alike problem

Answer (score 6):

I have similar issues from time to time - usually when switching from and to branches with lots of changes.

Clearing `jest`'s cache solved my issues.

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest --clearCache
```

More details on [clearCache](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#clearcache).

You could also check `jest`'s [showconfig](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#showconfig) and manually delete `cacheDirectory` location - same thing `clearCache` does.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unforunately it didn't :( I have also tried --no-cache parameter with no results as well. Sometimes it does work, sometimes not

Comment: Could it be a problem with running your tests in parallel? - maybe mocking some modules that are used in other tests?
What happens if you run your tests serially with [runInBand](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#runinband)?

Comment: it seems that this is a cause and a solution. Huge thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Did you the test that was causing this? `runInBand` works but it does take longer for the tests to run.